# How to handle large amounts of data?

Tags: java, performance, large-data

I have a project for school where I was given 103MB of data (Water Stream Quality Results in Ontario) which equates to 200 000+ lines of data.  I need to be able to take in the data and create a visual out of it (e.g. a map of Ontario with dots representing where X chemical was found in 20XX).

I have tried taking in everything more or less all at once which my computer obviously couldn't handle.  I was wondering if there is a strategy or function that can help me with this.

I would preferable like to have the information in a 2D ArrayList after the data has been taken in.

---

**Example**

Array Name: rawData

[0], [1], [2]

2002, 2003, 2004

station num, station num, station num

chem. found, chem. found, chem. found

etc.

If this is an inefficient way to have the data stored, what would be a better way?

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Side Note: the data has been given to me over 10+ files. Also, the file extension is a .csv so each row is separated by a comma (e.g. [year, chemical found, concentration percent>, etc.])

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Take a look at Microsoft Excel for this data.

Comment: @RichardChambers nice joke

Comment: import your data into a mysql database. This will allow you to manipulate the data easily without having to load it all into memory or parse files which is slow. Java has good support for working with mysql databases: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: You write `I have tried taking in everything more or less all at once which my computer obviously couldn't handle.`, but **WHAT** have you tried? ;-)

Comment: @Kiwy, using Excel is actually a serious idea.  Looking over what the question is about, being able to read in the data is probably the simplest part of the problem.  There is the whole graphing and plotting issue.  Here is an [overview of Excel Power Map](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2013/09/25/power-map-for-excel-earns-new-name-with-significant-updates-to-3d-visualizations-and-storytelling.aspx) with a link to the download for the plug in.  Excel was just the first that came to mind.  There are other applications.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @RichardChambers often when someone ask something in one technology it's because he needs to use it. Here it's clear that it's an excercice for school, so changing technology is not an option. And yes excel sharepoint and access does allow people to do very nice thing, but most of the time in an unreliable unmaintainable and one shot. but that's only my opinion.

Comment: @RichardChambers - Because it's for a student project. Also, if your solution does other things that excel can't, nobody wants to have to switch between multiple running programs to do one task when it can all be done in one place.

Comment: Don't even think about using Excel or MySql. Not only it adds a huge dependency to your small program and make it much harder to deploy and use, but it hardly helps. Using a DB might be a good idea, but then look for h2database (pure Java). Forget Excel, it's pure non-sense, surely not that fast, and Windows-only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ArrayLists. Create a class with the values you need to store in the objects.

For eg :

```
class Data{
  String Year;
  String found;
  ---one property for each of the value you need--
}
```

You can then populate the objects of this class and add them to the arrayList.

Comment: If this had a brief few words explaining how to use a BufferReader to pull the details over to the new Data object constructor it would be perfect.

Comment: @RudiKershaw I guess he has already figured that out while trying to put it into arrays

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ardash's answer, you will probably need to read in the data in chunks. If you use a BufferedReader, you can read CSV files line by line.